# Map elements in dataset to div id

Tags: html, d3.js

I would like to make a webpage that looks something like the following:

[image: a infographic titled 'Mapping Dog Care Manuals' with subheadings such as 'Edibles' and 'Bowl and plate design' accompanied by coloured dots representing different manuals.]

More specifically, I would like my webpage to be generated based on a dataset that has four columns, titled as follows:

- Manuals (there are four unique elements in this category, and they determine the colour of the dots)
- Name (this category determines the words that appear on mouseover)
- CategoryLevel1 (this category positions together rows that have the same CategoryLevel1)
- CategoryLevel2 (this positions together CategoryLevel1 data).

Update: figured out a strategy: run nest function and create multiple svgs based on keys.  Add squares representing entire dataset to svgs, then use opacity to hide the ones that are not relevant.

Problem lies in this line: `.attr("opacity", function(d, i) {return d.CategoryLevel1 == nest[p].key ? 1 : 0})`.  Although `nest[p].key`  works perfectly fine earlier in the code (see console.log on line 106), it seems to behave differently when in a block for creating rectangles.  Does anyone know how to make it behave?

```js
var doc = `Manual Name CategoryLevel1 CategoryLevel2
DOG "General Furry, Program and Subject Files" Average Quantity and Planning Edibles
TR Senate Committee on animal Standards Bowl and Plate Design Edibles
TR Published Canine Bowl and Plate Design Edibles
TR Canine case files Bowl and Plate Design Edibles
DOG Canine Files  Avoiding Neck Strain Edibles
DOG Canine Files  Drooling Edibles
DOG Canine Files  Drooling Edibles
DG ADVERTISING At home At home
DG PROMOTIONS At home At home
DG3 Publications At home At home
TR Public and Information Services At home At home
TR Petting Services Getting special treats At home
TR Petting Services Getting special treats At home
TR Petting Services Getting special treats At home
TR Petting Services Getting special treats At home
TR Petting Services Getting special treats At home
TR Petting Services Getting special treats At home
DG DEVELOPMENT Optimal time of day - walking Walks and outings
DG INCOME AND REVENUE Optimal time of day - walking Walks and outings
TR Fundraising Optimal time of day - walking Walks and outings
TR Fundraising Optimal time of day - walking Walks and outings
DG DEVELOPMENT Optimal time of day - walking Walks and outings
DG INCOME AND REVENUE Optimal time of day - walking Walks and outings
TR Wishbone Protective Measures Walks and outings
TR Wishbone Protective Measures Walks and outings
DG Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Walks and outings
DOG Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Walks and outings
TR Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Walks and outings`;

const data = d3.tsvParse(doc, function(d) {
    return {
      Manual: d.Manual,
      Name: d.Name,
      CategoryLevel1: d.CategoryLevel1,
      CategoryLevel2: d.CategoryLevel2
    };
  });


    var nest = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.CategoryLevel1;
      })
      .entries(data);



    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0)

    var height = 100,
      width = 200;

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#edf8fb", "#b3cde3", "#8c96c6", "#88419d"]);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height", "100%").attr("width", "100%");

    var g = d3.select("svg").attr("height", "100%").attr("width", "100%");



    var svgs = d3.select("body")
      .selectAll("svg")
      .data(nest)
      .enter()
      .append('svg')
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height + 20);

    svgs.append("text")
      .attr('class', 'label')
      .data(nest)
      .attr('x', width / 2)
      .attr('y', height)
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.key;
      })
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')

    for (var p = 0; p < 9; p++) {

      nest.forEach(function(element) {

        console.log(nest[p].key);


        svgs.selectAll("rect")
          .data(data)
          .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("height", function(d) {
            return 50;
          })
          .attr("width", "5")
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * 10;
          })
          .attr("y", 0)
          .attr("opacity", function(d, i) {
            return d.CategoryLevel1 == nest[p].key ? 1 : 0
          })
          .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.Manual)
          })

          .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
            div.transition()
              .duration(200)
              .style("opacity", .9);
            div.html(d.Name)
              .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
              .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 50) + "px");
          })
          .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            div.transition()
              .duration(500)
              .style("opacity", 0);
          });


      });

    }
```

```css
.page {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.menu {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #B2D6FF;
  /* Medium blue */
}

.sidebar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #F09A9D;
  float: inline-start;
  display: block;
  margin: 0.1%;
  /* Red */
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: inline-start;
  /* Yellow */
}

div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mapping Dog Care Manuals</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>


</html>
```

Comment: Seems like you are able to use arrays and objects as datapoint, if you need to insert icons, wouldn't it make sense to consume array of icon objects somewhere in data matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mess around with indices, modulo operators or things like that, as advised in the [<strike>accepted</strike> other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55192487/5768908) (in which the answerer honestly admits it's a hacky solution).

To get the datum of the parent SVG, just do:

```
const x = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var doc = `Manual Name CategoryLevel1 CategoryLevel2
DOG "General Furry, Program and Subject Files" Average Quantity and Planning Edibles
TR Senate Committee on animal Standards Bowl and Plate Design Edibles
TR Published Canine Bowl and Plate Design Edibles
TR Canine case files Bowl and Plate Design Edibles
DOG Canine Files  Avoiding Neck Strain Edibles
DOG Canine Files  Drooling Edibles
DOG Canine Files  Drooling Edibles
DG ADVERTISING At home At home
DG PROMOTIONS At home At home
DG3 Publications At home At home
TR Public and Information Services At home At home
TR Petting Services Getting special treats At home
TR Petting Services Getting special treats At home
TR Petting Services Getting special treats At home
TR Petting Services Getting special treats At home
TR Petting Services Getting special treats At home
TR Petting Services Getting special treats At home
DG DEVELOPMENT Optimal time of day - walking Walks and outings
DG INCOME AND REVENUE Optimal time of day - walking Walks and outings
TR Fundraising Optimal time of day - walking Walks and outings
TR Fundraising Optimal time of day - walking Walks and outings
DG DEVELOPMENT Optimal time of day - walking Walks and outings
DG INCOME AND REVENUE Optimal time of day - walking Walks and outings
TR Wishbone Protective Measures Walks and outings
TR Wishbone Protective Measures Walks and outings
DG Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Walks and outings
DOG Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Walks and outings
TR Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Walks and outings`;

const data = d3.tsvParse(doc, function(d) {
  return {
    Manual: d.Manual,
    Name: d.Name,
    CategoryLevel1: d.CategoryLevel1,
    CategoryLevel2: d.CategoryLevel2
  };
});


var nest = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.CategoryLevel1;
  })
  .entries(data);

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0)

var height = 100,
  width = 300;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#edf8fb", "#b3cde3", "#8c96c6", "#88419d"]);

/* var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height", "100%").attr("width", "100%");
    
var g = d3.select("svg").attr("height", "100%").attr("width", "100%"); */



var svgs = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("svg")
  .data(nest)
  .enter()
  .append('svg')
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height + 20);

svgs.append("text")
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .data(nest)
  .attr('x', width / 2)
  .attr('y', height)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')

svgs.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return 50;
  })
  .attr("width", "5")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * 10;
  })
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("opacity", function(d, i) {
    const x = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
    return x.key == d.CategoryLevel1 ? 1 : 0;
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.Manual)
  })

  .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", .9);
    div.html(`${d.Name}`)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 50) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  });
```

```css
.page {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.menu {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #B2D6FF;
  /* Medium blue */
}

.sidebar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #F09A9D;
  float: inline-start;
  display: block;
  margin: 0.1%;
  /* Red */
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: inline-start;
  /* Yellow */
}

div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I am guessing this is what you were expecting it to behave like.

Since in svgs.selectAll().data(data) part you are looping over each svg and data elements. 
So you are looping (data.length * svgs.length) times.

I do no not have a clean solution to your problem. But I did figure out a hacky way to solve it.

I use a global variable "index" to keep track of how many times it's looping over data and compare it with current svg element in question. I use index to deduce which is the current svg element that is being looped over.

```
.attr("opacity", function(d, i) {
        console.log(index)
        const x = nest[(index - i) % nest.length]
        index++;
        console.log(x.key, d.CategoryLevel1)
        return x.key == d.CategoryLevel1 ? 1:0;
})
```

Here's the complete fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/q0b8u63L/4/

**EDIT**
Ah, I guess I tried too hard to be smart with the deduction. I see what the problem with getting the remainder is. Instead you can just increment index if the loop has reached data.length - 1. Basically, compare each line with the next element in the `nest` when the inner loop has gone through all of the elements in `data`.

```
const x = nest[index]
index = (i == data.length - 1) ? ++index : index;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q7ocjw89/

Comment: This is brilliant.  Also, I made an adjustment - added your code to the height attribute, rather than the opacity attribute, to stop the tooltip appearing when people moused over the invisible bars: `.attr("height", function(d, i) {
           console.log(index, i)
           const x = nest[(index - i) % nest.length]
            index++;
            console.log(x.key, d.CategoryLevel1)
           return x.key == d.CategoryLevel1 ? 50:0;;
          })`

Comment: I am glad this worked for you :) . Yes, the height, width of non members can be set to 0 or their mouseover function to do nothing.

Comment: Just so you know, I tried to apply this to my real dataset (which has 682 lines, and 140 keys), and I came to the realization that the modulo you provided only works when the dataset happens to be 28 lines and 9 keys - there's something about these numbers that leads to precisely the correct remainder of 0 for the results of the first loop, 1 for the second loop, etc.) Anyway, your solution is still useful because it groups relevant shapes together.  I'm going to see if I can get a sort going.  Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Thank you very much for the creative solution.  I picked the other answer though because I prefer a single function (going to have to repeat this process multiple times, and a single function is less likely to fall victim to one of my errors.)

Comment: I figured there has to be better solution. I am not too great with d3 XD